# To use shouldRasterize or not to use

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to optimise performance on my app, and playing around with `shouldRasterize`.

I have a background view with a opaque subview on top. 
If I set the subview to `shouldRasterize`, it turns yellow when checking the "color offscreen-render".

If I have understand it correctly, you should try to minimize the offscreen-render, but shouldRasterize normally increase performance on a static subview that won't change?

Should I keep `shouldRasterize` on or off here?

Thanks

Comment: Now a more calm version of the above: performance of your app depend on many things that only you know about your app so we can't really tell you what is better *and neither can you* without good data. Measure with and without and compare the two. Preferably on multiple devices (not the simulator(!)). Also, keep in mind that certain "optimizations" can impact your apps memory usage.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `shouldRasterize` option is no silver bullet and it depends entirely upon what the view does. In my experience, it helps when performing animation of some view for which redrawing it from scratch is very expensive. But as David suggest, you should let your empirical results on devices dictate your final assessment of when and where you use it. See the Rasterization discussion roughly 13:20 into the [WWDC 2012 Polishing Your Interface Rotations](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=240) video.

Comment: This is the exact thing. Good catch!